# How to get number of entities to update properly

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data

I am adding an entity from `AddPetViewController`, which works fine unless I cancel. When I tap the cancel button, all it does it pop back to `MainTableViewController` but it adds an extra cell to the top of the top. Now if I select the last cell or try to add another entity(without cancelling) the app crashes.

**MainTableViewController.swift**

```
var petCount = 0
lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Pet> = {
    let fetchRequest = PersistenceManager.shared.fetchRequest()
    let context = PersistenceManager.shared.context
    let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    return frc as! NSFetchedResultsController<Pet>
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(pushToAddPetViewController))
    tableView.register(MainTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    do {
        try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
        petCount = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects!.count
        tableView.reloadData()
    } catch let err {
        print(err)
    }
}

@objc func pushToAddPetViewController(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AddPetViewController") as! AddPetViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
}
```

**AddPetViewController.swift**

```
let pet = Pet(context: PersistenceManager.shared.context)

@objc func cancel() {
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}

@objc func saveContext() {
    pet.name = nameTF.text
    pet.isBoy = isBoy!
    pet.isDog = isDog!
    pet.breed = breedTF.text
    pet.isVaccinated = isVaccinated!
    pet.weight = weightTF.text
    PersistenceManager.shared.saveContext()
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Both buttons work as they should but a new cell gets added no matter what I do. It should also mention that the new cell added when tapping `cancel()`, the blank cell doesn't exist if I reopen the app.

Comment: you should make It to where when you press cancel it erases the array made from it

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that since nothing is happening between the time I open the second view controller and hitting cancel. all I'm doing is pushViewController then popViewController

Comment: are you adding to the array at all?

Comment: I have a save button in the second view controller to save core data.

Comment: I think that might be the issue, make sure your not triggering it from anything like when you close it don't allow it to save. if you won't mind me asking what does the second vc do?

Comment: I edited the question to clarify what the second VC does. If there is anything else needed, let me know.

Comment: what about when you open press the add button? or the button that relays the second VC to open make sure your not adding another index

Comment: I added viewDidLoad() and pushToAddPetViewController functions to the question.